# xml created from dataframe in R does not open in explorer

Tags: r, xml

I have just learnt about xml and intended to turn my dataframe in R into xml, so that it could be used for corpus analysis. I am not using the conventional tagging label because of the nature of the data. The output does look right in the r console, but when I tried to open it in an explorer as a check if the xml is right, it shows nth in the explorer...so does it mean my xml is not right?

## here is my r code:

```
comments$text<-gsub("&","&amp",comments$text)

comments$text<-gsub("<","&lt",comments$text)

comments$text<-gsub(">","&gt",comments$text)

comments$text<-gsub("\n"," <n/> ",comments$text)

top= newXMLNode("CWII Step 1_1") 

o=newXMLNode("conversation",parent=top) 

 kids = lapply(comments$text[comments$parent_group==comments$parent_group[3]],

    function(x)

    newXMLNode("u",x,))
    addChildren(o,kids)

    saveXML(top, file="CWII Step 1_1.xml")
```

## this is what is shown in r console

```
<CWII Step 1_1>
<conversation>
<u>Hello!!! I am a person from India !!!!</u>
<u>Hi . When I think of your country India I i.</u>
</conversation>
</CWII Step 1_1>
```

## #

it seems like an xml to me, but unfortunately it does not show up when i open the .xml file in explorer, although it does show in notepad well with all tags

Comment: What is your current working directory? Find it with `getwd()`, then check that directory. Either `setwd()` at beginning of script or use absolute paths when saving files to disk.

Comment: By the way, that is not a well-formed XML. Element names cannot have spaces.

Comment: Thanks Parfait for pointing out that my element names is wrong. after changing this, it works well now! thanks a lot!